# Chrome extension - "Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

Trying to communicate between my background.js and contentscript.js

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],

    "description": "xxx",
    "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
               "48": "icon48.png",
               "128": "icon128.png" },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title" : "xxx",
        "default_icon": "icon16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches" : [ "http://*/*" ],
        "js" : [ "contentscript.js", "jquery.js" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
var listePdt = {};
var selectedPdt = null;
var selectedId = null;

function updatePdt(tabId)
{
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {}, function(pdt) {
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    });
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, change, tab) {
    if(change.status == "complete")
    updatePdt(tabId);
});

chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId, info) {
    selectedId = tabId;
    // and other things
});

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    updatePdt(tab.id);
});
```

**contentscript.js**

```
if(window == top)
{
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
        function(req, sender, sendResponse) {
            sendResponse(findPdt());
        }
    );
}

var findPdt = function() {

    // operations on a string

    return "string";
}
```

But I get the following error "Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist" in console for generated background page ... dont understand why .

Any help plz ?

Comment: I may be missing it, but where are you sending a message to your content script? I see the listener but no `sendMessage` methods.

Comment: My bad, I forgot a part of my code when I simplified it.
I edited, it's ok now, sry.

Comment: No worries - I dropped in a possible answer to you question, with the overall gist being that you will get that message on certain types of pages (New Tab, Extensions, Bookmarks, etc.).

Comment: Let me know if the below answer worked out for you - happy to keep brainstorming if not :)

Comment: Sorry for being late, but yes your solution is right ! Thx

Comment: Awesome man, happy to hear it! Good luck with everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that stands out is:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    updatePdt(tab.id);
});
```

It is currently deprecated (see [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/xNBppAYB4IQ) and [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#16)), and the new way looks like this (note that `windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT` is included as well to account for cases where you have multiple Chrome instances open (I had a number of them, apparently :) ).

```
chrome.tabs.query(
  {windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT, active: true}, function(tab) {
  updatePdt(tab.id);
  } );
```

However as to your main problem, this (and `getSelected`) will both throw the `Port` error you are seeing when you load the extension from `chrome://extensions`, the `New tab` screen, or any other 'non-standard' page (Bookmarks, View Source, Inspect Element itself, etc.), so I would just disregard them. With your code, reload the extension, open your Inspect Element window, then go to another tab in your browser and reload the page - you should see the desired action complete (I added a `console.log(pdt);` call as part of the `sendMessage` call, and the requested value was returned. In other words, everything seemed to work fine :)

Comment: Also be sure to check out the inspector for background pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension